# Subquery returns more than 1 row MySQL Error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get three columns of data. Date, Last Years Rev, This Years Rev.

Here is what I have, but I get an error: "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

However the goal is to have more than 1 row.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y%m%d") AS `Date`,
    (SELECT `amount` AS `Revenue($)` 
        FROM `payments`
        WHERE YEAR(date) = (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1)) AS `Revenue PY($)`, 
    (SELECT `amount` AS `Revenue($)`
        FROM `payments` 
        WHERE YEAR(date) = (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))) AS `Revenue CY($)`
FROM `payments`
GROUP BY `Date`
```

Sample Data:

```
date       | amount
2017-05-17 | 100
2017-05-17 | 200
2017-01-12 | 300
2018-05-17 | 330
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Date       | Revenue PY($) | Revenue CY($)
2017-05-17 | 300           | 0
2017-01-12 | 300           | 0
2018-05-17 | 0             | 330
```

Comment: Why use a sub-query?

Comment: that was the only way I could figure how to get both this year and last year. I am guessing from your question, that it was the wrong approach

Comment: Your sub-queries should also have group by (or similar) to limit them to 1 row, or have the amount column inside a function like sum. See my answer below for the later.

Comment: I am going to graph the data so I am actually looking for each payment in row with its date, rather than totals.

Comment: So, one row per payment, with a total for this year and last year?

Comment: Also, you should avoid using "special" character in column names. It's allowed, but can cause problems in the code receiving the results.

Comment: kinda, one payment per row grouped by date. so if there happen to be payments on the same day they would be the same row, no totals needed. The chart is going to be line chart comparing year over year.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: Try the edited answer below and let me know if it's close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166131/discussion-between-darkspartan47-and-sloan-thrasher).

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 Have you checked whether you subqueries returning more than one row or not???  If yes, then it's a good starting place to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y%m%d") AS `Date`,
    `amount`,
    (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `Revenue($)` 
        FROM `payments`
        WHERE YEAR(date) = (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1)) AS `Revenue PY($)`, 
    (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `Revenue($)`
        FROM `payments` 
        WHERE YEAR(date) = (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))) AS `Revenue CY($)`
FROM `payments`
GROUP BY `Date`
```

**UPDATE**

This should get the results as in your updated question. It gets a list of current year records and another list of previous year records, then combines them based on date. In order to combine rows from the same month/day from the two years, it adds a column sort_date which omits the year.

```
SELECT `date`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m%d') as `sort_date`,
    SUM(`Revenue CY`) as `Revenue CY`,
    SUM(`Revenue PY`) as `Revenue PY`
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y$m$d') as `date`,
        0 as `Revenue PY`,
        sum(`amount`) as `Revenue CY`,
    FROM `payments`
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y$m$d') as `date`,
        sum(`amount`) as `Revenue PY`,
        0 as `Revenue CY`,
    FROM `payments`
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
    )
GROUP BY `sort_date`
ORDER BY `sort_date`
```